# What triggers the guardians to reveal their weak spot?

Tags: shadow-warrior-2013

I am stuck at the second guardian. I was running away and dodging his attacks for like 50 minutes and he never landed and revealed his weak spot. Therefore, I cannot continue.

Does anyone know what exactly triggers them to show their little nooks to shot at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really made clear in the game, but you have to keep shooting the slightly highlighted parts to trigger the Boss to reveal his weak spot.

Answer (score -1):

Shine your sword at it! That'll reveal the marks.